# Angular views and ASP.NET MVC Views in the same folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am developing an application in Angular and ASP.NET MVC. I would like to keep some Angular partials and MVC partials in the same folder because they are logically related.  For example:

- /MyApp/Widgets/Image-config.html
- /MyApp/Widgets/Image-designer.html
- /MyApp/Widgets/Image.cshtml

I was able to make the Widgets folder used as a shared partial folder by adding this to Global.asax:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine
        {
            PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[]
            {
                "~/Widgets/{0}.cshtml",
                "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"                    
            }
        });
```

And copying the web.config from the default Views folder.

However, now I get a 404 when Angular goes to get the .html templates.  Is there any way to configure the Widgets folder such that it can both serve up static files and be a location for my server-side partial views?

Comment: The problem will be the web.config file ASP.NET MVC adds to the Views folder by default. The configuration settings inside this config file map all requests to the "not found" handler. The idea is that an MVC view should never receive a direct request, the request should always go through a controller. You'll either have to remove that configuration or change it to only reject requests for .cshtml file.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is create controller methods and use partial views, so my angular views are `.cshtml` too.  The url for your angular view is then the url for the controller action returning the partial view.

Comment: Hmm. It crossed my mind.  I just figured static .html would serve up faster and with less overhead if it didn't need to involve loading up the controller and view engine.